# the issue of Row length is 0 comes up when running "hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.Import "

Tags: hbase, hadoop2

I'd like to copy a table from hbase version 0.98 cluster to hbase version 1.2.0-cdh5.7.3 cluster.

run the command:

```
hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.Import -Dmapreduce.job.queuename= -Dhbase.import.version=0.98 -Dmapreduce.map.speculative=false -Dmapreduce.reduce.speculative=false
```

but I've got such error as:

```
Error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Row length is 0
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Mutation.checkRow(Mutation.java:534)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Put.<init>(Put.java:110)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Put.<init>(Put.java:68)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Put.<init>(Put.java:58)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.Import$Importer.processKV(Import.java:199)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.Import$Importer.writeResult(Import.java:164)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.Import$Importer.map(Import.java:149)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.Import$Importer.map(Import.java:132)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:145)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:787)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at    org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1693)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
```

Comment: can anyone give some suggestion on how to resolve the issue?in reality, the origin table doesn't contain any rows with empty or null rowkey.

Comment: even doesn't have any rows with rowkey matching ^/s+$

Answer (score 0):

I just experienced this issue - migrating data from an Old IBM Big-Insight system into HDP.

What I did to resolve this was

Write a HappyBase Program to step through the hBase table (in steps of 100 key values)....

Every several Million or so  - the Python code would stop....

In an *hbase shell*, I did a scan in the same key range, and I could see I had mal-formed data in the column.

My specific data was mal-formed utf-8 data, causing the codec to have issues.

I manually removed the Column - and repeated the steps....

When a table that can be 'scanned', I now carried out the Hbase Export, followed by Hbase Import - and it all worked.

You may be able to improve on this using Spark, by Exporting the data, copyToLocal and then using Spark reading the Sequence File as an RDD. Then apply your data filtering rules.